# A2032: Invalid use of register

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, mov

I have a line of assembly that read as follows:

```
mov target[sizeof source - ecx],byte ptr ebx
```

However, I'm getting the error `A2032: Invalid use of register`

As far as I know, I'm not doing anything wrong, but, apparently, I am.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which assembler are you using?

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? I think the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32800827/509868) by rkhb misinterpreted the goal of your code, but cannot be sure. Can you express your code in any language other than assembly? (English or C would be best)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two errors:

The assembler doesn't know what `byte ptr ebx` is and the processor cannot subtract `ECX` (it can only add).

I guess, the following sequence does what you want:

```
neg ecx                              ; Change sign
mov target[sizeof source + ecx], bl
neg ecx                              ; Restore ECX (if needed)
```

Comment: How do I get past the `byte ptr ebx`?

Comment: Nevermind. I just went with your example and instead of trying the `byte ptr ecx`, before that I just `mov bl,ecx` so your example works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to store a single byte (i.e. mov with operand-size = 8bit), then the `byte ptr` goes before the address, not before the register.

```
mov byte ptr [base + constant + ecx], bl  ;  bl is the low byte of ebx
```

The assembler takes care of adding `target + sizeof source` at assemble time into a single displacement to encode into the machine code.  As far as instruction encoding, it's just an offset from a register, regardless of whether the constant or the register has "the pointer" or "the array index".

`offset1[offset2 + reg]` looks unusual, and probably doesn't work on all variants of Intel-syntax.  (It reminds me of AT&T syntax is `offset(%ecx)`, where offset can be a sum of any assemble-time constants).

---

[The diagram in the x86 wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#x86_registers), shows which byte registers are subsets of which larger registers.  It's kind of cluttered; I think I've seen better diagrams somewhere else.  Maybe some of the other links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info will help.

Anyway, if you want to store the low byte of ebx at `[target + source - ecx]`, you do need to negate ecx first.  rkhb's answer looks good for that.

You commented that

```
mov bl,cl
```

was somehow helpful.  That seems very strange.  You're now storing the low byte of the address offset, rather than the low byte of whatever was in ebx before.